# ReactJS - exact same elements behave differently when scaling up/down in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, google-chrome

I'm trying to achieve a section in a website that some absolute position indicators are placed on a relative position timeline with ReactJS, everything is all good until I scale up/down the website on the browser. Here's a minimal example that describe the problem:

Timeline:

```
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="timeline">
      <div className="indicator one"></div>
      <div className="indicator two"></div>
      <div className="indicator three"></div>

      <div className="indicator four"></div>
      <div className="indicator five"></div>
      <div className="indicator six"></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

the css:

```
.timeline {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.indicator {
  position: absolute;
  height: 35px;
  width: 4px;
  background-color: #a43725;
}

.one {
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
}
.two {
  top: 50%;
  left: 31%;
}
.three {
  top: 50%;
  left: 32%;
}

.four {
  top: 60%;
  left: 40%;
}
.five {
  top: 60%;
  left: 41%;
}
.six {
  top: 60%;
  left: 42%;
}
```

Here is what the minimal example looks like, I have 6 absolute positioned rectangles which look exactly the same on relative position yellow background. One/two/three is a group (at the top) and four/five/six is another group (at the bottom). Everything looks good at 100% scale:
[image]

However when I scale it to 110% at the browser, it looks like this:
[image]

It is obvious that there's a line between rectangle one and two, but not between the other rectangles.

Which I think rectangle #1 does not scale as large as other rectangle? The problem is I am making a timeline thing and the rectangles are some kind of indicators that has to be (and supposed to be) visually looking the same as each other at any scale. Why does it behave differently and how can I fix it?

p.s. here is a [js fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/kep7o4tq/) for the minimal example but because the screen there is smaller the behaviour is a little bit different. The issue can be reproduced by resizing + scale up and down the small browser area. Here's a screenshot to proof that the issue appears in the fiddle.
[image]

*I have only test this in Chrome and not sure how it behaves in other browsers*

Comment: Can you please share the jsfiddle link with the minimal example

Comment: @FreemanLambda sry, I forgot to append the link. I edit the question with the link and gonna post it here too: https://jsfiddle.net/kep7o4tq/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your issue is that the positioning is dependent on the timeline and the timeline is 50% width (half the screen) so the positioning is heavily dependent on the screen size as well

the following worked:

```
.one {
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(30% + 0px);
}
.two {
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(30% + 5px);
}
.three {
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(30% + 10px);
}

.four {
  top: 60%;
  left: calc(40% + 0px);
}

.five {
  top: 60%;
  left: calc(40% + 5px);
}
.six {
  top: 60%;
  left: calc(40% + 10px);
}
```

I also found some similar issue with the vertical positioning of the indicators if the height of the screen size changes to fix this would be better if the portion of the screen you want is fixed height

Answer (score 0):

From my testing the issue is that you have pixel width for your indicators, but the position is % based. When you zoom in, the width of your element is shrunk which means the 1% gap gets smaller and smaller, to a point where the indicator's width of 4 pixels is larger than the gap between them.

One fix I found, was to give the indicators `max-width: 0.75%;` which would mean the scale along to keep at least 0.25% gap between each other. Going the other way too you could add `min-width: calc(1% - 4px);` or whatever sized gap you would like.

https://jsfiddle.net/nrk39yfq/

Answer (score 0):

As @roy-el-hajj mentioned your solution is dependent on the width of the screen.

Basically there's a threshold where the difference in positioning between two indicators (1%) is smaller than the width of the indicators (4px).

So either use Roy's solution which will maintain the relative distance between the lists and the edges of the screen (50%/30% and 60%/40%) but use `calc` to set the width between the indicators to 1px.

Or set all distances (top/bottom) in pixels.
Or set the width of the indicators in percentages (looks like 0.6% works to make sure they never overlap)